# in python, can there be multiple keys of the same name within one dictionary? if so, how would you delete a specific one?

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, key

in python, can there be multiple keys of the same name within one dictionary? if so, how would you delete a specific one?

Comment: no, [keys must be unique](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: no i didn't, sorry :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `Dictionary` must have unique key since it uses `hashing algorithm`

Comment: is there a way do make something similar to a dictionary (with keys and values) where two 'keys' could be the same?

Comment: @smellyhead What is your use case? For most cases it makes sense to use the key if it exists. If you have a duplicate you get confusion.

Comment: what i need is a dictionary with various companies (key) and the product number of their product

Comment: eg: dict{company_1 : 123456, company_1 : 234567, company_2 : 987654} @ak_slick

Comment: Use a list for the value: `{'company_1': [123456, 234567], 'company_2': [987654]}`

Answer (score 0):

If you think you need this your best move is probably to put a list into a dictionary. It's quite a bit more code to handle but it gets the job done.

On the other hand, needing to ask this question is usually, but not always, a sign you're doing something wrong.